# waitForTransform gets slower and slower

Tags: ros, python, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04.

I'm using openni_tracker v0.2.0. I'm trying to write a python script that draws an arrow between the user's head and right hand, using frames published by the skeleton tracker.

The two transforms `kinect_link -> head_1` and `kinect_link -> right_hand_1` are both getting published consistently at a rate of 30 hz.

Here are two snippets of my code:

```
  1. tf_listener.waitForTransform('head_1', 'right_hand_1',  rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(0.5))
  ...
  2. hand_pose_hand_frame = PoseStamped()
  3. hand_pose_hand_frame.header.frame_id = 'right_hand_1'
  4. hand_pose_hand_frame.pose.orientation = Quaternion(w=1.0, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0)
  5. hand_pose = tf_listener.transformPose('head_1', hand_pose_hand_frame)
```

I need line 5 because I'm drawing the arrow in the `head_1` frame. I've found that if I don't include line 1, then line 5 will often fail because the transform doesn't exist. However, line 1 is problematic. The longer my code runs, the slower line 1 runs, until eventually every call times out. I used python's `time.clock()` to profile my code's performance over time:

[image: image description]

Since the necessary transform information is getting published at 30 hz the whole time, I can't figure out what `waitForTransform` is actually waiting for.

How can I fix my call to `waitForTransform` so that it has the same performance at T=25 as it does at T=5?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211112/waitfortransform-gets-slower-and-slower/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2015-06-11**:
How many other frames are being published on your system, and at what rate?

What does `rostopic hz tf` give you?

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-06-11**:
15 frames are being published at 30 hz and 4 frames are being published at 10 hz

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-06-11**:
`rostopic hz tf` yields lots of lines similar to
`average rate: 497.771`
   `min: 0.000s max: 0.035s std dev: 0.00671s window: 981`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out! I was creating a new TransformListener each iteration of my loop. By only creating one TransformListener and reusing it for every call, I can now run my main loop as fast as I want. (With no forced delay, it runs at 300 hz!)

Just for fun, here's another graph of the problematic version. (yellow and blue use the left y-axis, red uses the right)
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) with karma: 233 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asaglam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45229/asaglam/) on 2021-02-20**:
Thanks a lot for this quick tip! I was looking for various ways to handle the slow transformation. Thanks to this, I speed up my program. Nevertheless, I should have paid enough attention when creating the instance of TransformListener at every iteration.